# With one extreme

Tags: cryptic-clues

```
Al and a maniac, without me, consult fact book (7)
Ask to firstly-excluded Jew to get tilted (5)
Avoid a French green (5)
Conduit lacking on front defense trails birds without road pastry (7)
Confused knight's assistant is obscene (6)
Even book area is a plant (4)
Infinity is me in castle, confused (10)
Steal damaged file within processor bounds (6)
```

This was intended to be short. Looking for an eight-letter answer. Enjoy, I guess.
(Also my first try at cryptic clues; I need feedback :D )

Comment: I think there's an indirect anagram there...

Comment: yep @Sid found it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filling in the bits Omega Krypton has left:

Ask to firstly-excluded Jew to get tilted (5)

> ASK+(j)EW = ASKEW

Conduit lacking on front defense trails birds without road pastry (7)

> C(ond)UIT trails BI(rd)S making BISCUIT

Infinity is me in castle, confused (10)

> MEINCASTLE* = LEMNISCATE

and then

> the first letters, suitably ordered, spell out PARABOLA, a shape "with one extreme".

A little feedback:

> OK has already remarked on the indirect anagram. Don't do that :-). Otherwise, they're all more or less sound (there's an extra "a" and for that matter an extra "consult" in #1; and I'm not too keen on "firstly-excluded" meaning removing the first letter; aside from the indirect anagram, risque really isn't the same as obscene) and I think the biggest weakness is that the surface readings are mostly not great. (Birds without road pastry? Book area?) I don't think I have much in the way of advice on making clues with good surfaces, other than keeping the structure of the wordplay in mind as you decide on the wording and keeping the surface in mind as you think about the wordplay. All of which is easier said than done :-).

Comment: Lemniscate is not infinity though. It's the symbol for infinity. (But of course. That's not on you)

Comment: @Sid Yes, agreed.

Comment: i appreciate the feedback :0 i'll keep these tips in mind.

Answer (score 2):

### Partial Answer

Al and a maniac, without me, consult fact book (7)

> ALMANAC: AL + MANIAC - I

Ask to firstly-excluded Jew to get tilted (5)
Avoid a French green (5)

> AVERT: ddef

Conduit lacking on front defense trails birds without road pastry (7)
Confused knight's assistant is obscene (6)

> RISQUE: Indirect anagram :( *SQUIRE (knight's assistant)

Even book area is a plant (4)

> OKRA: _O_K _R_A

Infinity is me in castle, confused (10)
Steal damaged file within processor bounds (6)

> PILFER: P_ *ILFE _R

### Some feedback:

> Most are fine, and kudos to you if this is your first attempt doing cryptics! But then indirect anagrams such as the one with RISQUE is not recommended. Keep it up!

Comment: all so far are correct :0